# Are two URLs identical? Ignore the param order

Tags: php, url, duplicates, query-string

I have two URLs and am looking for the best way to decide if they are identical.

Example:

```
$url1 = 'http://example.com/page.php?tab=items&msg=3&sort=title';
$url2 = 'http://example.com/page.php?tab=items&sort=title&msg=3';
```

In the two URLs only the `sort` and `msg` param are switched, so I consider them equal. 
However I cannot simply do `if ( $url1 == $url2 ) { … }`

I'm having a list of URLs and need to find duplicates, so the code should be fast as it is run inside a loop. (As a side note: The domain/page.php will always be same, it's only about finding URLs by params.)

Comment: Turning the params into an associative array, then using array_diff could be a good way to go

Comment: You'd need to combine [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) and [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str). Either comparing the param arrays, or sort'em and reassemble urls.

Comment: Parse the parameters with `parse_str`, sort them with `ksort`, then put them back. Then you can compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
function compare_url($url1, $url2){
  return (parse_url($url1,PHP_URL_QUERY) == parse_url($url2,PHP_URL_QUERY));
}
```

Comment: That's perfect :-) I only use `parse_url()` instead of `preg_replace()`. Very good idea to compare the param-arrays!

Answer (score 1):

It's not as easy as it might sound to find out if an URI is identical or not, especially as you take the query parameter into account here.

One common way to do this is to have a function that [normalizes the URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization) and then compare the normalized URIs:

```
$url1 = 'http://example.com/page.php?tab=items&msg=3&sort=title';
$url2 = 'http://example.com/page.php?tab=items&sort=title&msg=3';

var_dump(url_nornalize($url1) == url_nornalize($url2)); # bool(true)
```

Into such a normalization function you put in your requirements. First of all the URL should be normalized according to the specs:

```
function url_nornalize($url, $separator = '&')
{
    // normalize according RFC 3986
    $url = new Net_URL2($url);
    $url->normalize();
```

And then you can take care of additional normalization steps, for example, sorting the sub-parts of the query:

```
    // normalize query if applicable
    $query = $url->getQuery();
    if (false !== $query) {
        $params = explode($separator, $query);
        sort($params);
        $query = implode($separator, $params);
        $url->setQuery($query);
    }
```

Additional steps can be though of, like removing default parameters or not allowed ones, or duplicate ones and what not.

Finally the string of normalized URL is returned

```
    return (string) $url;
}
```

Using an array/hash-map for the parameters isn't bad as well, I just wanted to show an alternative approach. Full example:

```
<?php
/**
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27667182/are-two-urls-identical-ignore-the-param-order
 */

require_once 'Net/URL2.php';

function url_nornalize($url, $separator = '&')
{
    // normalize according RFC 3986
    $url = new Net_URL2($url);
    $url->normalize();

    // normalize query if applicable
    $query = $url->getQuery();
    if (false !== $query) {
        $params = explode($separator, $query);
        // remove empty parameters
        $params = array_filter($params, 'strlen');
        // sort parameters
        sort($params);
        $query = implode($separator, $params);
        $url->setQuery($query);
    }

    return (string)$url;
}

$url1 = 'http://EXAMPLE.com/p%61ge.php?tab=items&&&msg=3&sort=title';
$url2 = 'http://example.com:80/page.php?tab=items&sort=title&msg=3';

var_dump(url_nornalize($url1) == url_nornalize($url2)); # bool(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that both URLs are identical, we need to compare at least 4 elements:

1. The scheme(e.g. `http`, `https`, `ftp`)
2. The host, i.e. the domain name of the URL
3. The path, i.e. the "file" that was requested
4. Query parameters of the request.

Some notes:

- (1) and (2) are case-insensitive, which means `http://example.org` is identical to `HTTP://EXAMPLE.ORG`.
- (3) can have leading or trailing slashes, that should be ignored: `example.org` is identical to `example.org/`
- (4) could include parameters in varying order.
- We can safely ignore anchor text, or "fragment" (`#anchor` after the query parameters), as they are only parsed by the browser.
- URLs can also include port-numbers, a username and password - I think we can ignore those elements, as they are used so rarely that they do not need to be checked here.

---

**Solution:**

Here's a complete function that checks all those details:

```php
/**
 * Check if two urls match while ignoring order of params
 *
 * @param string $url1
 * @param string $url2
 * @return bool
 */
function do_urls_match( $url1, $url2 ) {
    // Parse urls
    $parts1 = parse_url( $url1 );
    $parts2 = parse_url( $url2 );
    
    // Scheme and host are case-insensitive.
    $scheme1 = strtolower( $parts1[ 'scheme' ] ?? '' );
    $scheme2 = strtolower( $parts2[ 'scheme' ] ?? '' );
    $host1 = strtolower( $parts1[ 'host' ] ?? '' );
    $host2 = strtolower( $parts2[ 'host' ] ?? '' );
    
    if ( $scheme1 !== $scheme2 ) {
        // URL scheme mismatch (http <-> https): URLs are not identical.
        return false;
    }
    
    if ( $host1 !== $host2 ) {
        // Different host (domain name): Not identical.
        return false;
    }
    
    // Remvoe leading/trailing slashes, url-decode special characters.
    $path1 = trim( urldecode( $parts1[ 'path' ] ?? '' ), '/' );
    $path2 = trim( urldecode( $parts2[ 'path' ] ?? '' ), '/' );

    if ( $path1 !== $path2 ) {
        // The request-path is different: Different URLs.
        return false;
    }

    // Convert the query-params into arrays.
    parse_str( $parts1['query'] ?? '', $query1 );
    parse_str( $parts2['query'] ?? '', $query2 );

    if ( count( $query1 ) !== count( $query2 ) ) {
        // Both URLs have a differnt number of params: They cannot match.
        return false;
    }

    // Only compare the query-arrays when params are present.
    if (count( $query1 ) > 0 ) {
        ksort( $query1 );
        ksort( $query2 );

        if ( array_diff( $query1, $query2 ) ) {
            // Query arrays have differencs: URLs do not match.
            return false;
        }
    }

    // All checks passed, URLs are identical.
    return true;
} // End do_urls_match()
```

---

**Test cases**:

```php
$base_urls = [
    'https://example.org/',
    'https://example.org/index.php?sort=asc&field=id&filter=foo',
    'http://EXAMPLE.com/p%61ge.php?tab=items&&&msg=3&sort=title',
];

$compare_urls = [
    'https://example.org/',
    'https://Example.Org',
    'https://example.org/index.php?sort=asc&&field=id&filter=foo',
    'http://example.org/index.php?sort=asc&field=id&filter=foo',
    'https://company.net/page.php?sort=asc&field=id&filter=foo',
    'https://example.org/index.php?sort=asc&&&field=id&filter=foo#anchor',
    'https://example.org/index.php?field=id&filter=foo&sort=asc',
    'http://example.com:80/page.php?tab=items&sort=title&msg=3',
];

foreach ( $base_urls as $url1 ) {
    printf( "\n\n%s", $url1 ); 
    foreach ( $compare_urls as $url2 ) {
        if (do_urls_match( $url1, $url2 )) {
            printf( "\n  [MATCHES]  %s", $url2 );
        }
    }
}

/* Output:

https://example.org/
  [MATCHES]  https://example.org/
  [MATCHES]  https://Example.Org

https://example.org/index.php?sort=asc&field=id&filter=foo
  [MATCHES]  https://example.org/index.php?sort=asc&&field=id&filter=foo
  [MATCHES]  https://example.org/index.php?sort=asc&&&field=id&filter=foo#anchor
  [MATCHES]  https://example.org/index.php?field=id&filter=foo&sort=asc

http://EXAMPLE.com/p%61ge.php?tab=items&&&msg=3&sort=title
  [MATCHES]  http://example.com:80/page.php?tab=items&sort=title&msg=3

*/
```